# How to Install Fedora (not create bootable USB)

Tags: fedora, software-installation, usb, bootable

I have searched Google for how to download Fedora, and all I find is how to create bootable USB.

Once I load Fedora from bootable USB how do I permanently install Fedora from USB onto my laptop?

Comment: Does the [installation guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Installation_Guide) help? Why not?

Comment: @ckujau Thank you for posting the link. When I searched Google, I didn't find, otherwise I wouldn't have posted here. Have a nice day.

Comment: Searching for "[how to download Fedora](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+download+Fedora&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8Ik2VfORG8PkaObJgCA)" got me plenty of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not obvious enough from the documentation, but: once you have that bootable USB media and boot it ***to the live environment***, there is a window with two big choices: *Try Fedora* or *Install to Hard Drive*:

[image]

Hopefully, everything should be clear from there. (And if you choose to "try" initially and close that window, there is  an installer icon on the dash.)

Comment: ahhh, but I didn't see the option to "Install to Hard Drive" when I booted to Fedora. When I created bootable USB for Ubuntu, that option to install to hard drive was right on the desktop. I shall check again ...... So far I get option "start fedora live"

Comment: You'll see this _from_ the live environment.

Comment: will try this out soon ....

Comment: @mattam I am in Live Environment and am looking for window two two big choices ..... will keep looking .....EDIT: I downloaded 32bit version. When I search image for this big window, I am taken to download page for 64 bit version ....

Comment: will try to download 32bit version from here, https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ws-download-splash?file=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/21/Workstation/i386/iso/Fedora-Live-Workstation-i686-21-5.iso

Comment: I must have gotten a defective image, will make sure this image shows this big window

Comment: Well, what _are_ you seeing?

Comment: I see a multicolor desktop and icons are hidden. Now, I'm downloading another iso ....

Comment: I finally installed to hard disk ..... now I need to set up wifi ....

Comment: Okay. That's another question. :)

Comment: I can figure this out :-)